# Get d3.svg.symbol() center

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm using the function `d3.svg.symbol()` to plot symbols on a scatterplot. I'd like to have some tooltip show up on mouseover on the symbols. To place them accordingly, I need to get the center of the symbols, but don't really know how to do this. The code I use to generate the symbols is:

```
var symbols = svg.append("g")
            .attr("id", "circles")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x(d[SelX]) + "," + y(d[SelY]) + ")"; })
            .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol()
                .size(50)
                .type(function (d) { if (d.Spaziatura == "Proportional") { return "circle";} else { return "diamond"; }; }))
            .attr("fill", function (d) {
                if (d.Grazie == "Sans") { return colore(parseFloat(d[SelCol])); } 
                else { return colore2(parseFloat(d[SelCol])); };
                })
            .attr("id", function (d) { return d.FamilyName;})
            .attr("opacity", 1)
            .attr("visibility", "visible")
```

Then the mouseover event:

```
        .on("mouseover", function (d) {

            //Get this symbbol's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
            var centroid = symbols.centroid(d);
            var xPosition = centroid[0];
            var yPosition = centroid[1];

            //Update the tooltip position and value
            svg .append("text")
                .attr("class", "tooltip")
                .attr("x", xPosition)
                .attr("y", yPosition - (height/20))
            //and then other stuff happens
```

I tried to reuse the centroid function I used for a map, but it doesn't work. I just need to get the center of the symbol's path to get this working, so any help on this is really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Could you get the bounding box and compute the center of that?

Comment: I've never really used BBox, will look into it

Comment: solved it using d3.select(this).node().getBBox

Comment: Nevermind, with .node() I get the same bbox for all the symbols, maybe it gets calculated on all the symbols as they were one big element?

Comment: Could you provide a complete example in a jsfiddle please?

Comment: here it is (it's the same file I already asked for help over and over :) ) http://jsfiddle.net/G8G2N/
Right now many things are not working correctly, because I changed circles for shapes, but the thing that is more important is the tooltip now, because I can't make that work

Comment: Have you tried something like `var bbox = this.getBBox();` in your mouseover function?

Comment: now I tried setting this.getBBox(); but the result looks the same to me: http://i.imgur.com/8tgnzmE.png as you can see the x coordinates for the tooltips are set to 0

Comment: Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/G8G2N/1/) do what you want?

Comment: what I'm trying to achieve is this tooltip popup when doing a mouseover on the sumbols: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37967455/prova_dropdown_assi.html
With the cricles it was easy to get the center coordinates, but with symbols I don't know how to do that

Comment: That's what I've done in that modified jsfiddle. Are the coordinates that this gets you the ones you're looking for?

Comment: Yes sorry it works perfect. I wasn't seeing any tooltip showing so thought you posted that by mistake. Thanks, if you want to post that  part in the answer I'll mark it as correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the center of the symbol like this (in the mouse handler):

```
var bibox = this.getBBox(),
    t = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform")),
    centroidX = t.translate[0] + (bibox.x + bibox.width)/2,
    centroidY = t.translate[1] + (bibox.y + bibox.height)/2;
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G8G2N/1/).